# How to find most common element in common lisp list?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Say we have a list with these elements:

("apple" "pear" "apple" "banana" "pear" "apple")

How to determine that most common element is this list is "apple"?

Comment: Make a hash table whose keys are the strings and values are the number of times they've been found in the list. Loop through the list incrementing `(gethash element hash-table)`. Then when you're done loop through the hash table and find the key with the highest value.

Comment: The interesting question is what would it be if you had one more pear in that list?

Comment: Your code contains commas between elements in a context where it is invalid. You should remove them to have valid CL code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is quite broad, so here below is a utility function that groups elements into bags of same frequencies. The primary return value is a hash-table where keys are positive numbers (number of occurrences) and values lists of elements. All those lists form a partition of `elements`.
The secondary return value is the intermediate frequency hash table, which  might be useful for the caller. You should be able to find the most frequently occurring  element(s) with that.

```
(defun frequency-bags (elements &key (test #'equal))
  (let ((frequencies (make-hash-table :test test))
        (bags (make-hash-table :test #'eql)))
    (dolist (e elements) (incf (gethash e frequencies 0)))
    (maphash (lambda (k v) (push k (gethash v bags))) frequencies)
    (values bags frequencies)))
```

### References

[`make-hash-table`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_has.htm)
[`gethash`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_gethas.htm)
[`maphash`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_maphas.htm)
[`dolist`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw61/CLHS/Body/m_dolist.htm)
[`values`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_values.htm)
[`setf`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/m_setf_.htm)
[`push`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_push.htm)

### Examples

```
(alexandria:hash-table-alist 
 (frequency-bags
  '("apple" "pear" "apple" "banana" "pear" "pear" "apple")))

=> ((1 "banana")
    (3 "pear" "apple"))

(alexandria:hash-table-alist 
 (frequency-bags
  '("apple" "apple" "orange" "peach" "banana" "pear" "pear" "apple")))

=> ((2 "pear")
    (1 "banana" "peach" "orange")
    (3 "apple"))
```